# Who proved this theorem which is critical to prove the Fubini

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

> Let $(X,\mathfrak{M},\mu),(Y,\Sigma,\nu)$ be sigma-finite measure spaces.
>
> Let $E\in \mathfrak{M}\otimes\Sigma$
>
> Define $\varphi(x)=\nu(E_x), \forall x\in X$
>
> Define $\lambda(y)=\mu(E^y), \forall y\in Y$
>
> Then, $\varphi,\lambda$ are measurable and $\mu\times\nu(E)=\int_X \varphi d\mu = \int_Y \lambda d\nu$.

Who proved this theorem? Fubini?

The proof for this seems very beautiful.

And did the one who proved this theorem also invent the idea of attacking sigma-algebra via monotone class?

Answer (score 1):

This is known as Fubini's Theorem, but it is very unlikely that the original version of this Theorem looked anything like the version your are referring to.

Nevertheless, the version of Fubini (1879-1943) was indeed about integrals on product measures and not about Riemann's integral on rectangles, which is also known as Fubini's Theorem.

Comment: This is, unofficially speaking, "incomplete fubini's theorem". Both Rudin and Folland first prove this and then prove the Fubini's theorem. So do you mean Fubini invented an idea of monotone class?

Comment: And it's amazing to know that legitability of Iterated integral was first proven for measure space, not Riemann.